# Set theory and relations - Is this relation reflexive or irreflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have just started learning set theory and need an explanation on how to go about this question:

Is the relation, "xRy if and only if (x - y) > 0 and (x - y) < 3" reflexive or irreflexive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I noted on a similar Question you posted recently, more context is needed to define a relation $R$.  In particular, you need to tell Readers what kind of things $x$ and $y$ the relation is supposed to apply to.  Are these real numbers, or something else?  The several mentions of "set theory" do not clarify your setup.

Comment: Apologies, "A group of relations, all acting on the set of real numbers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reflexivity, we need to check whether $xRx$ holds for all $x,$ which is equivalent to $0<x-x<3,$ which however is false for all $x$ (since $x-x=0$). In fact, this shows that *no* element is in relation to itself, so $R$ irreflexive.